# How to get certain Tag Values

Tags: python, html, selenium, automation

The following Selenium automated script correctly opens the given URL and opens the View Invoice tab that opens up a detailed Invoice.
I need to fetch some values like Number, Date and table values from the detailed invoice. The values are very nested to get to them correctly. The URL that opens up when the View Invoice is clicked, I don't know how to **scrape** it or use selenium to proceed with.
Is the element in the code like an instance to get the values of the opened detailed invoice page or is there some different approach?

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'D:/Chrome driver/chromedriver.exe') # Get local session(use webdriver.Chrome() for chrome) 
driver.implicitly_wait(3)

driver.get("URL") # load page from some url

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='PNRId']").send_keys("MHUISZ")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='GstRetrievePageInteraction']").click()

element = driver.find_element_by_name('ViewInvoice')
element.click()
```

Can anyone please guide me on how to fetch the values from the invoice page?

Comment: Hi there if you want to simply get the value of those tags first find the element. Then use .text.

Comment: Hi Arundeep, to find the tags I used the element to find the tags and did use the .text method. But it gives **NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element**. Am I suppose to use this "element = driver.find_element_by_name('ViewInvoice') " element to fetch the values?

Comment: When you get a nosuchelement exception there are a variety of reasons that you may not be able to get it try wrapping the driver.findbyelemet in a webdriver wait.

Comment: You want to get the values on the next page.

Comment: element.click() opens up a detailed page and I need to fetch the values of that page for this what locator am I suppose to use the element or driver? I tried wrapping it with wait doesn't work.

Comment: Ok I have an example for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So try to wait for elements to be visible or clickable and your clicking on the invoice actually creates new child handles so you have to switch to them. All you have to do now is figure how to go through a table try looking through it's xpath.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'D:/Chrome driver/chromedriver.exe') # Get local session(use webdriver.Chrome() for chrome) 

driver.get("URL") 
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='PNRId']"))).send_keys("MHUISZ")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='GstRetrievePageInteraction']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'ViewInvoice'))).click()
p = driver.current_window_handle
#get first child window
chwnd = driver.window_handles
for w in chwnd:
   #switch focus to child window
   if(w!=p):
       driver.switch_to.window(w)
       break
invoiceTable = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "TableHeader")))
print(invoiceTable.find_element_by_xpath("tbody/tr[1]/td").text)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: ok so element.click() was a new handle and I had to switch on that to access the elements on that window. Thank you, it worked. In a similar way, I am supposed to get other values. Does diver.window_handles gets all the windows that are opened?

Comment: It does so you can switch back.

Comment: Mark the answer as accepted if you need help with the others just comment.

Comment: Sure. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/q/63867576/14263707